# Unabel to login to wordpress's admin area when tried to install the backup on Xampp (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, xampp, localhost, backup

I have recently a problem with my website which was built on WordPress. Therefore I decided to install xampp on my Ubuntu 18.04 and try to tackle the issue on a localhost. I did make a new user using "privileges" tab on localhost/PhpMyadmin and did "sudo mv wordpress /opt/lampp/htdocs". So my old website could be linked to the new database. My old website is now accessible through http://localhost/wordpress/ but it does now show all the contents and lack many things. It also does not let me to enter the Admin area through the login address. I should mention that While my webpage was working properly I did change the login address from .../wordpress/wp-admin/ to .../wordpress/loginWebName.

Comment: Did you updated the `siteurl` and `home`  option_name  in `options` table ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps.

1. Install WP-CLI
   Follow: https://wp-cli.org/#installing
2. Go to the Wordpress site folder in terminal
   Using: cd /path-to-wordpress/
3. Configure wp-config.php with new database password
4. Use below command to replace your existing siteurl to new one.

   wp search-replace "existing-url" "new-url"

   - If you are working on localhost new-url will be localhost/relative-path-to-wordpress.
   - Check site-url value in wp_options table for existing-url